# Issue when creating on-to-many relationships in SQLAlchemy database

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I created a Flask app with a database, with following classes:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Category'
    children = relationship("Child")
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text())
    icon = db.Column(db.Text())
    subcategories = db.relationship('Subcategory', backref="category")

    def __init__(self, name, subcategories, icon):
        self.name = name
        self.color = icon
        self.subcategories = subcategories


class Subcategory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Subcategory'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text())
    color = db.Column(db.Text())
    reward_points = db.Column(db.Integer())
    category = db.Column(db.Text())
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref="subcategory")
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))

    def __init__(self, name, color, reward_points, category, tasks, category_id):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.reward_points = reward_points
        self.category = category
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.category_id = category_id


class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Task'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    task = db.Column(db.Text())
    start = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    end = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer)
    scheduled = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    status = db.Column(db.Text())
    category = db.Column(db.Text())
    subcategory = db.Column(db.Text())
    tags = db.Column(db.Text())
    subcategory_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subcategory.id'))

    def __init__(self, task, start, end, duration, category, subcategory, tags, created, status, scheduled, subcategory_id):
        self.task = task
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.duration = duration
        self.category = category
        self.subcategory = subcategory
        self.tags = tags
        self.created = created
        self.status = status
        self.scheduled = scheduled
        self.subcategory_id = subcategory_id
```

My goal is to create one to many relationships between the classes. I am trying to run the db.create_all() command, but am getting following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'Subcategory.category_id' could not find table 'category' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

What am I doing wrong? Other questions on Stackoverflow with similar issues did not resolve my error.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

`category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))`

to

`category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Category.id'))`

solved the issue.

Changing "category.id" to "category.c.id" solved the issue as well. If anyone knows why, pls let me know ;-)